# If statement failing in Perl

Tags: perl

I seem to have problems with this *if* statement. It logically seems like it works. I want to look to see if the array is defined. If it is defined, look to see if the word matches. But whenever I enter a word that does not match is still seems to be entering the *if* statement.

```
if(@split_array and
   ($split_array[0] eq "cd"    or
    $split_array[0] eq "set"   or
    $split_array[0] eq "alias" or
    $split_array[0] eq "last"  or
    $split_array[0])
   )
{

}
```

Comment: What do you suppose that last `or $split_array[0]` part is testing for?

Comment: What is the last `$split_array[0]` for? That seems to cause the problem.

Comment: That must have been a typo, Ive fixed it now

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
   ... or $split_array[0]
```

This part means that if you have a value in `$split_array[0]` that is defined and not zero or empty, your if will always be true.

Try some formatting to more easily spot mistakes. Like this:

```
if (
    @split_array and
    (
        $split[0] eq "cd" or 
        $split[0] eq "set" or 
        $split[0] eq "alias" or 
        $split[0] eq "last" or 
        $split[0]
    )
) 
{ ... }
```

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
if (@split_array and $split_array[0] =~ /^(?:cd|set|alias|last)$/)
{
    # ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
or $split_array[0]))
```

at the very end of the statement.  You aren't comparing it, so I'm guessing that's returning true for any word.

Comment: Thanks!, I didnt notice that. Ive fixed it now

Comment: Hmm, the guy answer the question first, his proposed solution worked, the OP confirmed, and the correct mark goes to the other answer. Interesting. (Take it easy TLP, it's not an attack)

Comment: @sidyll, the check is not for the *one* correct answer, or the *first* correct answer, but it's for what the OP thinks is the **best** answer. Often times that belongs to the answer that goes the extra step to not just solve the current problem but provide information about that problem and/or solution. In this case while Kendrick has the right answer, TLP showed how simple code legibility would make the problem obvious from the start.

Comment: @Ven'Tatsu I understand completely. The point was that  5 minutes later this answer was posted the OP said it worked in a comment. At this point, this answer and the other were basically the same (except that this one was posted earlier). Then, 20 min later (after the problem was already solved) TLP edited his answer to show the formatting trick. The times are not that precise now, but on that moment I was just wondering how come that "Thanks it's solved" and not marked as correct. Anyway, that was just a comment and I'm not attacking anyone, just trying to show that time should be considered.

Comment: @sidyll I suspect the OP mixed our answers up. I fully expected to "lose" this one, since Kendrick did beat me by 4 minutes. I added the formatting because I thought it would be helpful to avoid problems with long conditionals like this.

Comment: @TLP valuable edit by the way! I also upvoted yours. Anyway, the discussion I started was (or should be) "momentary" :-) as we sometimes fight for seconds here in StackOverflow; and I didn't get what was the OP waiting to mark it as correct (since he already spent time saying "thanks it works". Anyhow, I'm happy to see that you're not angry with me :P or something like. I really expect that we leave this comments subject now. It shouldn't be on air for that long… Thanks for your comprehension and best regards for everyone.

Comment: @sidyll Thanks for noticing :-)  No worries either way though.  I got more rep than I deserve for spotting a simple error, and I don't know perl so I couldn't have come up with your answer, which is really probably the best one.